# Set condition in while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have the following C# source:

```
public static bool PeulaRashit()
{
    int days;
    double totalPayForService;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of days");
    days = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
    if (days== 999)
        return false;
    totalPayForService = TotalService(days);
    TotalPyament(totalPayForService, days);
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (.....) //what should I do here?
    {}
}
```

I want the `PeulaRashit` method to repeat until it is `false`.
My question is what should be the condition in the `while` so it will happen?

Comment: O_O just Google how to use a while loop...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (PeulaRashit())
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
while (PeulaRashit())
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is :

```csh
bool loop = true;
while(loop) {
    loop = PeulaRashit();
}
```

which could be written :

```
while(PeulaRashit());
```

Comment: This probably ought to be the accepted answer, as the simplest method is clearly all the OP requires.